# How to select Scored Probabilities from azure prediction model

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a model in AzureML that scores incoming values from a csv.

The flow is ...->(Score Model using one-class SVM)->(Normalize Data)->(Convert to CSV)->(Convert to Dataset)->(Web Service Output)

When the experiment is run I can download the csv from the (Convert to CSV) module output and it will contain Scored Probabilities column.

But when I'm using a streaming job I don't know how to access the Scored Probabilities column using Query SQL. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the response using the amlresult.[Scored Probabilities] notation, where amlresult is an alias for the return value from your AzureML call.